# How to format the date string in GanttView from Telerik for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, date-formatting, gantt-chart

As the question says, I want to know how I can format the date string of the start or end column in a GanttView from Telerik for WPF.

I already tried this to options:

```
<t:ColumnDefinition MemberBinding="{Binding Path=Start, StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}'}"
                    Width="AutoHeaderAndContent"/>
```

and:

```
<t:ColumnDefinition MemberBinding="{Binding Path=Start}"
                    Width="AutoHeaderAndContent">
    <t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue, StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For a normal `TextBlock` in WPF, this will work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
```

You can add time to it as well:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy - HH:mm:ss}"/>
```

But now that I am looking in the link you provided in the comments, it might be that you have to play with the `DataFormatString` in `ColumnDefinition`:

```
<t:ColumnDefinition MemberBinding="{Binding Path=Start}"
              DataFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy" Width="AutoHeaderAndContent">
   <t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>
```

See the following examples:

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddatetimepicker/how-to/use-in-grid

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/data-formatting

Comment: Where did you change it ? For normal TextBlock it works

Comment: <t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </t:ColumnDefinition.CellTemplate>

Comment: And it looks like this: 3/20/2018 12:04:22 PM

Comment: Do you get any binding exceptions in your output windows or Immediate window ?

Comment: Just to understand this telerik thing. Why do you bind to Start, and then later to FormattedValue ?

Comment: In a normal Grid your TextBlock would look for a property called FormattedValue in Start, eg. Start.FormattedValue

Comment: FormattedValue is predefined by this control. If I want to customize the column content I have to bind to this value. Telerik provide some examples on their site. [link](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radganttview/features/columns/cell-template)

Comment: Thanks I will try those two!